# Prove $\lim_{x \to \infty} e ^{ x} \sin{(x)}$ does not exist using the Heine–Cantor theorem.

Tags: calculus, limits

> **Theorem (Hein-Cantor)**. *Let $f\colon M\to N$ be a continuous function between two metric spaces $M$ and $N$. If $M$ is compact, then $f$ is uniformly continuous.
>
> In particular, if $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, then $f\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if and only if $f$ is uniformly continuous.*

The problem is the following:

> **Problem.** Using the Hein-Cantor theorem, prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}e^x\sin(x)$ does not exist.

I understand the Heine–Cantor theorem  but I don't know how to use it in this particular problem and what to use as $x_n$ and $y_n$. Can I just prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin x$ does not exist?

*Remark*: find $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\to \infty$ such that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)\neq\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n').$$

Comment: What is Heine's theorem in this case? And what have you tried?

Comment: What is the theorem itself? And oh dear, that green background. An edit to turn that picture into text would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the Hein-Cantor theorem has to do with this particular problem. For a solution not involving said theorem:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{n\pi}\sin(n\pi)=0\neq \infty =\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\pi(4n+1)/2}\sin(\pi(4n+1)/2).$$

Comment: How do you evaluate the first limit that equal 0 without using Del Hopital rule?

Comment: @Houda $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\; \sin(n\pi)=0$ since $\sin(\pi)=\sin(2\pi)=0$ and $\sin$ is $2\pi$-periodic. Similarly, $\sin(\pi(4n+1)/2)=1$ for every $n$.

Comment: What about the exp it will be 0× $\infty$

Comment: $\lim_n \big(e^{n\pi}\sin(n\pi)\big)=\lim_n \big(e^{n\pi}\cdot 0\big)=\lim_{n} 0=0$. 
It is not always true that $\lim a_n b_n=\lim a_n\lim b_n$ so  that reasoning doesn't work.

Comment: I see now thank you for explanation